# The system can't recognize the disk's space

Tags: hard-drive, gparted, external-hdd, gnome-disk-utility

So, recently i decided to remove ext4 partition from my external hard drive, which i used for Timeshift backups. I successfully removed it from 1tb external drive, but the file manager shows me that the disk only has 790.5gb, which is the same as it was before removing ext4 partition.
I tried to manipulate it with "Disks" app and Gparted as well.
When i try to resize the NTFS partition - after some time the process stops and Disks generates a window on the bottom of currently opened Disks window, which contains more Disks windows...
[See the screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J6pjV.png)
I also tried to "check and repair" the drive with Gparted, but after few seconds - the program just stops responding.
However, Disks shows that my main (ntfs) partition takes 1TB of space, while Gparted says that the disk has 150gb of free space.
I also tried to boot into Gparted Live, but i couldn't, for some unknown reason.
The problem is that i don't have full access to my 1TB of space and both software failed here. What can i do, to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

It may be helpful if you provide more information. Can you explain how you "removed" the ext4 partition from your external 1TB hard drive? Also, the picture you sent is very glitchy, which makes me believe that something's wrong in how the system is able to see the drive. Is your Timeshift (Steam game?) backup safely stored and usable on your computer? If so, I suggest you reformat that external hard drive **ONLY IF** you have nothing on it that needs to be moved to another drive. This might mean having to delete the partitions on the external drive, then formatting it accordingly, making sure that its new partition spans the entire 1TB range and is active, so that it can be usable again on Ubuntu. If there is a detail I have confused, feel free to drop a comment.

Comment: How i removed it: i selected the ext4 partition in Disks and pressed "delete selected partition".
Timeshift - is a software that i use to make backups of my system. I used it on my previous system long time ago, so i don't really need it any more. And my external drive is 600+gb full at the moment and i don't have any other drives to back up all those 600+gb, so i really can't format it. Also, the picture shows that window with other Disks windows. The display of other drives in the original window shows everything correctly

Comment: Oh, on my end I see a single window in the back that says 1TB and all the other ones on top have a glitchy look to them. Do you happen to had a command line utility like fdisk, or something similar you can use to view the status of the partitions? Because technically, you should be able to see the partition that's not ext with all of your stuff, and the rest as "free space".